# Overriding Java interface with overloaded vargs methods in Scala

Tags: java, scala

Is there a way to implement the following Java interface in Scala?

```java
public interface Request {
    void acceptLanguage(Locale... locales);
    void acceptLanguage(String... locales);
}
```

I tried:

```scala
override def acceptLanguage(locales: Locale*) : Unit =
override def acceptLanguage(locales: String*) : Unit =
```

But that gives me:

```
error: double definition:
have same type after erasure
```

And I tried this:

```scala
override def acceptLanguage(locales: Locale*) (implicit Manifest[Locale]) : Unit = {}
override def acceptLanguage(locales: String*) (implicit Manifest[String]): Unit = {}
```

But that gives a different signature so override fails

I am using version 2.9.2.

Answer (score 8):

Use `@varargs` annotation:

```
override def acceptLanguage(@varargs locales: Locale*) : Unit =
override def acceptLanguage(@varargs locales: String*) : Unit =
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track. According to what I found the 
annotation goes on the method though. I still get the following error:
    A method with a varargs annotation produces a forwarder method with the same signature

Comment: I made a small example with one method annotated with @varargs. The compiler generates two methods, one with Seq and one with an array. This is also done automatically by the compiler when the scala method overrides a java method with varargs. Since the methods with Seq still are generated the problem still happens

Comment: Right, my answer surely doesn't solve your problem. Sorry for being too hasty with my answer.